# How to find out what file triggered a batch?

Tags: file, batch-file, associations

I changed the file type association for .prt by using

```
ASSOC .prt=PartFile
FTYPE PartFile=C:\Users\...\Desktop\pass.bat %1
```

This opens another batch file when double clicking on a .prt file. I would like to know what the name of the file that was used with the double click, but the below code isn't working for me in the pass.bat file. Any help would be grateful!

```
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
echo %5
echo %6
echo %7
echo %8
echo %9
```

Comment: It works here as expected. Maybe the path to .bat file is wrong? Make sure there's `pause` at the end of .bat to actually see the output (sorry for the silly reminder). Anyway, provide more details on "code isn't working for me".

Comment: yes, I do have a pause at the end to see it. Besides that, everything you see is what I used. The batch script does popup, but for each echo, I just get ECHO is off.

Answer (score 0):

found another way to do it. I just changed the registry key for the classes:

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\secFile\Shell\Open\Command" /ve /d "\"%RegOpenPath%\" \"%%1\"" /f >nul
reg add "HKCR\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache" /v "%RegOpenPath%"  /d "%RegOpenName%" /f >nul
```